# "yeah I've heard it all before" or "yeah right"

Tags: word-choice

I'm struggling to think of a word to use for the title phrases.
The context would be someone promising to do something and it being met with the answer "yeah right" or "yeah I've heard it all before"
So I want to finish the sentence - This was initially met with ----

Comment: Both are fine ways of saying that you have little optimism in the outcome promised by your conversational partner.  "Doubt" is the word that describes the feeling.

Answer (score 3):

I confess your question is somewhat confusing to me.  My answer below is targetted towards your last sentence, "This was initially met with ----."

This word has fallen out of use, but [dubiosity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dubiosity) fits the context.

[Incredulity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incredulity) would fit the bill as well, but I think the answer you're looking for is [skepticism](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/skepticism)

Skepticism - a skeptical attitude; doubt as to the truth of something

"This was initially met with skepticism."

Comment: Thank you Lumberjack, scepticism is the word I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I like **apprehension** or **hesitation** depending on the exact meaning you want to convey.  Probably apprehension here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend ***misgivings*** or ***reservation***.

[***misgiving***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/misgiving?s=T)

> noun
> Often, misgivings. a feeling of doubt, distrust, or apprehension.

[***reservation***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reservation?s=t)

> an exception or qualification made expressly or tacitly:
>
> *to accept something, but with inner reservations.*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact exchange and the tone, the response could be considered **[dismissive](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dismissive)**

> reacting to something in a way that shows you do not think it is worth paying attention to

An alternative in the same vein is **[derision](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/derision)**

> the opinion that someone or something is stupid, unimportant, or useless

If the tone was not so pointedly negative, it might be considered **humoring**.  *[Humor](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/humor_2)* (the verb) is defined as

> to agree to someone’s wishes in order to help improve that person’s mood or to avoid upsetting him or her